# Regex to match Bearer token

Tags: regex

I'm having a bad moment trying to make a regex that can find line similar to this in files :

> Bearer 89abddfb-2cff-4fda-83e6-13221f0c3d4f

It should have Bearer at the begining followed by space, and the token after is the same format :
[hexadecimal, 8 char]-[hexadecimal, 4 char]-[hexadecimal, 4 char]-[hexadecimal, 4 char]-[hexadecimal, 12 char]

Any help would be very appreciated

PS: Maybe just the regex of the token format will be enough to find the token without the Bearer not sure

Comment: You should include code example of your attempt. Hint: Don't overcomplicate. Just grab the characters between "Bearer " and the end of line. You can use http://regex101.com for testing.

Comment: Agreed with @marekful with not overcomplicating it. I do a string split on whitespace with a limit of two items, make sure the first is "Bearer". Then later on you could add a validator for token format if it's really needed.

Comment: Why down vote ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RegEx tested with PowerShell

```
'Bearer\s[\d|a-f]{8}-[\d|a-f]{4}-[\d|a-f]{4}-[\d|a-f]{4}-[\d|a-f]{12}'
```

**Edit: shorter version**

```
'Bearer\s[\d|a-f]{8}-([\d|a-f]{4}-){3}[\d|a-f]{12}'
```

Comment: I accepted this answer as it's the most simplifed regex, thank

Comment: @Imad Here the shorter version actually takes more steps than other solutions, and also has a capture group which is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You may use regular expression:

```
^Bearer\s[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}$
```

or

```
^Bearer\s[a-f0-9-]{36}$
```

You can try the regexes live [here](https://regex101.com/r/lIhz8h/4/) and [here](https://regex101.com/r/lIhz8h/5).

Answer (score 2):

you can also use this regex **^(?i)Bearer (.*)(?-i)** as it will match for lower and upper cases too.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

data = "Bearer 89abddfb-2cff-4fda-83e6-13221f0c3d4f"

print(re.findall(r'(Bearer )([a-f\d]{8})-([a-f\d]{4})-([a-f\d]{4})-([a-f\d]{4})-([a-f\d]{12})', data))
```

The [explanation on Regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/HZm4Oo/1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RegEx [`Bearer [\da-f]{8}-[\da-f]{4}-[\da-f]{4}-[\da-f]{4}-[\da-f]{12}`](https://regex101.com/r/6iAgFS/1)

- `Bearer` matches `Bearer` litterally
- `[\da-f]` matches an hexadecimal value
- `{n}` matches the preceding group `n` times

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/6iAgFS/1)